# cube folding with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

I would like to fold 12 cubes to one. Please help me with this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%optional libraries
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows,automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usepackage[grapics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\tikz \pic [folding line length=10mm, numbered faces, transform shape]
  {cube folding};
face 1 = {\node {1};},
face 2 = {\node {2};},
face 3 = {\node {3};},
face 4 = {\node {4};},
face 5 = {\node {5};},
face 6 = {\node {6};},
face 7 = {\node {7};},
face 8 = {\node {8};},
face 9 = {\node {9};},
face 10 = {\node {10};},
face 11 = {\node {11};},
face 12 = {\node {12};}
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are several syntax problems:

- `\tikz` inside environment `tikzpicture`. This probably causes the messed up bounding box.
- The `pic` is finished after `{cube folding}`, but options follow as ordinary text (invisible because of `\nullfont`) with `\node` commands over printing, because they are all called at the same position (outside the folding pic).
- `numbered faces` or manual faces? The former is used in the simplified example at the end, the latter is used in the following example, it allows further modification of single faces.
- `cube` (6 faces) or `dodecahedron` (12 faces)?

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%optional libraries
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows,automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usepackage[grapics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path pic [
    folding line length=10mm,
    transform shape,
    % numbered faces,
    face 1 = {\node {1};},
    face 2 = {\node {2};},
    face 3 = {\node {3};},
    face 4 = {\node {4};},
    face 5 = {\node {5};},
    face 6 = {\node {6};},
    face 7 = {\node {7};},
    face 8 = {\node {8};},
    face 9 = {\node {9};},
    face 10 = {\node {10};},
    face 11 = {\node {11};},
    face 12 = {\node {12};}
  ]
    {dodecahedron folding};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [
      folding line length=10mm,
      transform shape,
      numbered faces,
    ]
    {dodecahedron folding};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```